# How to update the ScrollViewer after changing the width?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

In my scenario I have `Grid` Within `ScrollViewer` and set the `Grid` width and `Height` exactly fit in full screen (Grid width screen width), I increase change Grid with using Button click, now Horizontal scroll-bar appear so Horizontal scroll-bar appear.

After that, I reset the Grid Width to initial width, now scroll bar in visible only, but I need to hide that scroll bar, because I have initial Grid width only. How can I update `ScrollViewer`?

```
< ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    < Grid  x:Name="grid" Height="700" Width="1364">
        < Button Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Content="increaswidth" Height="40"/>
    < /Grid>
< /ScrollViewer>
```

.

```
bool flag = true;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (flag)
        grid.Width = grid.ActualWidth + 25;
    else
        grid.Width = 1364; 
    flag = !flag;
}
```